# How to specify Content-length header for AngularJS $http Post call

Tags: angularjs, ajax, post

I am executing a post request with AngularJS `$http.post(URL,data)`. However Content-Length header is not passed in the request header. How to specify the Content-Length header explicitly? I am able to set explicit headers with `$http.defaults.headers.common['key']=value;`. But since the content length is dynamic based on request data size, How to specify the header & its value in angularJS $http POST?

Comment: Check request in browser dev tools network. The browser should set it for you no?

Comment: @charlietfl The browser is not setting the header, checked in chrome as well as firefox